# How can I tell if a database record has changed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm writing a process that will run on a schedule and periodically scan records in a SQL Server database and check for changes to those records. Unfortunately the records in this database are not versioned/timestamped in any way and I can't change the schema because it's not my database. Short of comparing every single field I don't have any idea how to check to see if a change has actually occurred.

Right now I'm using entity framework for all data access, but I can switch to direct queries if needed. Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: I need a way to check each individual record for changes, not a database/table as a whole.

Comment: What would you compare the current version to to detect the change?

Comment: @EmmadKareem I'll have to have a second database that stores versioning info. So if I go with the hash method that Peri suggested below that second db will store the hash for each record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think checking each record can work for big databases (it can take forever)

But you could calculate hash for each row and store it in your apps database. Then on every run recalculate hash and compare with what's in your apps db.

Also I know you can't change schema, but maybe you could add triggers to monitored dataabse that will log changes?

Another option could be setting up replication and detecting changes (with triggers as above) in database that receive's replicated data (but I have to admit I never configured replication and I may be wrong about how it works).

Comment: Unfortunately triggers aren't an option either; the DBAs are already upset that a 3rd party is directly hitting their database. They definitely won't change anything for us. I know this isn't ideal but it's what I'm stuck with. Luckily the tables I'm working with only have a few thousand records, so I think the hash is a good option. Is there a way to do this with entity framework or will I have to do a direct query?

Comment: I would not use EntityFramework for this as this will only add overhead and not give you anything. Go for direct queries. For speed I would use SqlDataReader (not DataTables). Also in order to query db with EF you have to generate model in code for the database and regenerate it every time db changes (if you at all now that database changed). With direct queries database can change and you don't have to change your code (SELECT *)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or greater, you may be able to make use of either Change Data Capture or Change Tracking. Here's [a link to the MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx).